# How to change div card content on hover in vuejs

Tags: html, css, vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#mouse',
  data: {
    message: 'Hover Me!'
  }, 
  methods: {
    mouseover: function(){
      this.message = 'Good!'
    },    
    mouseleave: function(){
      this.message = 'Hover Me!'
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  
  background: #333;
  
  #mouse {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: block;
    width: 280px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #007db9;

    a {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mouse">
  <a
    v-on:mouseover="mouseover"
    v-on:mouseleave="mouseleave">
    {{message}}
  </a>
</div>
```

How to change div card content on hover in  vuejs?

with the help of below code, i am able to successfully change the content on hover. But only issue is.

intially i want to show some image. there after once if user hover the div. then i need to see button. in the same div(only after hover).

Comment: You need to return htmlElement instead of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS do to this for you:

```css
#myButton {
  display: none;
}

#mouse:hover #myButton {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="mouse">
  <a
    v-on:mouseover="mouseover"
    v-on:mouseleave="mouseleave">
    {{message}}
  </a>
  <button id='myButton'>Test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have a boolean, maybe `isHover` and you conditionally show you content. when mouseover, `isHover=true`, when mouseout, `isHover=false`

Comment: https://codepen.io/dhanunjayt/pen/XWgyqXW

Here is the code link i tried, but it doesn't work. is there any mistake i have done.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to show all the content in the same `div`. You can also put conditions to show which element at which time [example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if). And put the conditions for first-time show image using the `isFirstTime` boolean variable.

Comment: Here is the code i tried, But having issue like onhover the content is not changing
https://codepen.io/dhanunjayt/pen/XWgyqXW

When used the conditional rendering